# Mockito: How deep to stub?

Tags: java, mockito

I am new to JUnit testing with Mockito. I am struggling to figure out the "testing logic" problems, one of which is ***how deep to stub***.

Let me give a simple example:

Firstly, let's assume this is the class to be tested:

```
Class ToBeTested {
    public int a1() {}
    public int a2() {}
    public int a3() {}

    public int A() {
        return a1() + a2() + a3();
    }

    public int B() {
        temp = A();
        return temp++;
    }
}
```

When I try to write JUnit test, I am not sure how to stub these methods. For example:

```
@Test
public void testB() {
    ToBeTested mockedTBT = mock(ToBeTested.class);

    /*
     *Problem here: How Deep to stub?
     */

    //shallow stubbing
    BDDMockito.given(mockedTBT.A()).willReturn(6);

    //deep stubbing
    BDDMockito.given(mockedTBT.a1()).willReturn(1);
    BDDMockito.given(mockedTBT.a2()).willReturn(2);
    BDDMockito.given(mockedTBT.a3()).willReturn(3);

    int expected = 7;
    int result= mockedTBT.B();

    assertEquals(expected, result);
}
```

In this case, should I use the shallow stubbing or deep stubbing? Or can I follow any rules to write a reasonable test?

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mock the minimal amount required to test the behaviour you are focussed on.

In the example above, you seem to care that `B()` is calling `A()` and returning an incremented value. Therefore, just mock the response from `A()`.

You may later wish to test the functionality of `A()`, in which case you may choose to mock the other methods that `A()` calls.

Comment: Is it always true to just care about as much as possible? In other way, in testing, are we trying to isolate the method as much as possible?

Answer (score 2):

If you are truly doing unit testing, then *ideally* you should not stub any methods in the Class Under Test (System Under Test) -- rather only mock collaborator classes.  In your case, this suggests perhaps a "code smell" indicating that you possibly want to divide your class into more than one class, each with a well-defined set of responsibilities.

If you don't think the class needs to split, then for unit testing you need to treat it as a black-box, and just consider all of the different kinds of input conditions which are possible and drive that from the outside calls to your class rather than mocking out internal pieces.  I *love* Mockito and mocking, but there's a right and wrong place to use it.

Comment: thanks for pointing out this testing fashion. but as I don't have permission to change the source code, i can only try to test by violation some rules.

Comment: @thirty I don't understand... you are unit testing code that you don't have permission to change?  Then why are you testing it?

Comment: @thirty I second Kevin. Could you change code in case you found a bug? Sometimes code is written in a manner that makes it really hard to unit-test and really error prone. In these cases it's good practice to change source to be easier to use and unit-test. I have had same experience myself, thinking that legacy source is secret, and no mortal may touch it ever. It was written by mortals (maybe even by younger and stupider instance of yourself). Therefore it only makes sense to improve source by refactoring.

Comment: @Lauri, too true on the "even by younger and stupider instance of yourself".  That has been too often the case.